# How to create a JComboBox whose elements each have two different styles?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, renderer

I'm creating a Java application by using Swing. It contains a JTextField with a JComboBox which contains the last entered words with the time when these words were entered. The String with the time should be in another size and color (smaller and in light grey) as the last entered words (standard style). So in each element of the JComboBox should be used two different styles. How can I do that?

Comment: [How to use combo boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), [Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ComboSample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ComboSample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Combo example");
        final JTextField fld = new JTextField(20);
        TextData[] data = new TextData[]{new TextData("First", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000)), 
                new TextData("Second", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 200000)),
                new TextData("Third", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 300000)),
                new TextData("Fourth", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 400000))};
        JComboBox<TextData> cb = new JComboBox<>(data);
        cb.setSelectedItem(null);
        cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                TextData td = (TextData) cb.getSelectedItem();
                if (td != null) {
                    fld.setText(td.getText());
                }
            }
        });
        frm.add(fld);
        frm.add(cb, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TextData {
        private static final DateFormat FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        private final String text;
        private final Date timestamp;
        public TextData(String text, Date timestamp) {
            this.text = text;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "<html>" + text + " <span style=\"color:#D3D3D3\"><i>" +  FORMAT.format(timestamp) + "</i></span></html>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to choose a Look and Feel for that allow to achieve that.
Another way can be to create a different JLabel with the background color that you need for every JComboBox element and add them with:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Some text");
label.setBackground(Color.grey);
label.setOpaque(true);

jComboBox.addItem(label);

JLabel anotherLabel = new JLabel("Another text");
anotherLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
anotherLabel.setOpaque(true);

jComboBox.addItem(anotherLabel);
```